# Why Probaility that two guys are born in same month is 1/12 but not 1/2.

Tags: probability

Assuming that it is equally like to be born in any of the 12 months.

**Reasoning for 1/2**: Probability that both are born in the month of Jan is 1/12*1/12 as event must happen one after another. This probability is same for every other month. The event can happen in any of the 12 months, we need to add 1/24, 12 times. So we got 1/2.

**Reasoning for 1/12**: There are 144 total outcomes and 12 favorable outcome. All the event are equally likely so the probability is 1/12.

Where am I doing wrong? Please suggest.

Comment: For the first one, it should be $1/144$ $12$ times.

Comment: I don't understand. Is that $\frac{1}{12} \times \frac{1}{12}= \frac{1}{24}$? ;)

Comment: $$\frac{1}{12}\times\frac{1}{12}=\frac{1}{12\times 12}=\frac{1}{144}$$
$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{144}+\frac{1}{144}+\cdots+\frac{1}{144}}_{\text{12 times}}=12\times\frac{1}{144}=\frac{1}{12}$$

Comment: :-( My bad... Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

> Reasoning for 1/2: Probability that both are born in the month of Jan is 1/12*1/12 as event must happen one after another. This probability is same for every other month. The event can happen in any of the 12 months, we need to add 1/24, 12 times.

$\frac1{12} \times \frac1{12}$ is not $\frac1{24}$.